# How to remove whitespaces at the beginning of character using regexes in R?

Tags: regex, r

Does anyone know how to remove whitespaces at the beggining of those characters using regexes in R?

```
 c( "bundesliga" ,                                                                                                                                                                                                              
" liga niemiecka"  ,                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
"   wyniki na żywo" )
```

This doesn't seem to work:

```
lowered <- c( "bundesliga" , " liga niemiecka", "   wyniki na żywo" )
grep( x = lowered, pattern = "^\\s*(?=\\S)", value = TRUE, perl = TRUE )

   [1] "bundesliga"        " liga niemiecka"   "   wyniki na żywo"
```

Comment: `str_trim` from `library(stringr)` is a convenient function to use here. `str_trim(v1)`

Comment: If you are using `read.table` (or any `read.xxx`), you may set `strip.white = TRUE` - "allows the stripping of leading and trailing white space from unquoted character fields"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `gsub`:

```
gsub("^\\s*", "", c( "bundesliga", " liga niemiecka", "   wyniki na żywo"))
#[1] "bundesliga"     "liga niemiecka" "wyniki na zywo"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
^\s*(?=\S)
```

This should do it.Replace by `empty string`.

or

```
^\\s*(?=\\S) for r
```

Comment: lowered <- c( "bundesliga" , " liga niemiecka", "   wyniki na żywo" )
grep( x = lowered, pattern = "^\\s*(?=\\S)", value = TRUE )

Comment: @MarcinKosinski use `perl=True` option too

Comment: Added this option but still does not work

Comment: @MarcinKosinski if you are using `grep` use `gsub`